# JQuery change first found space to <br> after x characters

Tags: jquery

I have a unordered list that is used as a menu that I cannot directly add formatting to. Its styled in CSS as a horizontal menu and new items are to be added. In order to give a nice visual structure and minimise the width of each entry so that it all still fits I want to make the menu items/titles read as two lines, as most titles have 2/3 words. eg

eg I want "Cat & Dogs Houses" to format like

Cat & Dogs
Houses

The titles word count and lengths are variable but looking through them I think if I can follow a rule like "Insert 
 in first space found after 10 characters" it should all fall into place.

The site already has jQuery installed so using that is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

It's much preferable to use a delimiter if at all possible (e.g. "Cats & Dogs; Houses"). Edit whatever is feeding you the string of titles to include a delimiter as your solution won't work for certain titles. For example, if you reversed the order to "Houses Cats & Dogs", then the first space after 10 characters would resolve to

```
Houses Cats
& Dogs
```

However, if you don't want to listen to my advice, you could do this with pure javascript:

```
var string = "1234567890 Cats & Dogs Houses";
var inArray = string.split(" ");
var outArray = []

while (array.length != 0) {
   var tmp = array.shift();
   while (tmp.length < 9 && array.length != 0)
      tmp += " " + array.shift();
   newArray.push(tmp);
}
```